# Script to update your production DB from test DB

Tags: php, mysql

On my local computer I have a test environment running XAMPP. I am working on a PHP / MySQL application.

Now I often make changes to the local website, but when I want to upload I have to do a lot of work. This is what I do now.

I export my local DB trough phpMyAdmin
I clear my remote DB
I import the exported DB.

Sometimes the DB is kind of large so it takes a lot of time. Is there a script I can use that speeds up this process.

*I have no remote access to the production DB*
*When I make changes to the local DB the website is turned off, so its just a mirror when done*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Phing's DBDeploy Task](http://phing.info/docs/guide/stable/) to manage your database migrations. This has the advantage that any changes to your database become an integral part of your versioning system.

Here is an article describing how to do it:

- <s>http://www.davedevelopment.co.uk/2008/04/14/how-to-simple-database-migrations-with-phing-and-dbdeploy/</s> (now 404 - see comments)

Alternatives are Rob Allen's [Akrabat_Schema_Manager](http://github.com/akrabat/Akrabat) and I think Doctrine has one too.

Comment: The link to the article is now a 404. The google cache is at http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.davedevelopment.co.uk%2F2008%2F04%2F14%2Fhow-to-simple-database-migrations-with-phing-and-dbdeploy%2F

Answer (score 0):

Here is a backup and migration script that I use

```
#!/bin/bash

email="email@addresswherebackupissent"

dbhost="dbhost"
testdbname="testdbname"
productiondbname="productiondbname"
dbuser="dbuser"
dbpass="userpass"

mkdir -p ~/archives
cd ~/archives
suffix=$(date +%y%m%d)
echo "SQL Backup of \"$dbname\" attached" >> tmp.txt
mysqldump --opt -u $dbuser -p$dbpass -h $dbhost $testdbname > SQL_"$testdbname"_$suffix.sql

mysql -u $dbuser -p$dbpass -h $dbhost $productiondbname < ../backup/drop/drop.sql
mysql -u $dbuser -p$dbpass -h $dbhost $productiondbname < SQL_"$testdbname"_$suffix.sql

tar zcf SQL_Backup_"$testdbname"_$suffix.tar.gz *.sql
mutt -s "SQL Backup of \"$testdbname\"" -a SQL_Backup_"$testdbname"_$suffix.tar.gz $email < tmp.txt
rm -rf {*.sql,tmp.txt}
```

This script can be run executed from the shell and will backup your DB and email it to you, and then .  The file drop.sql is a copy of the drop commands phpmyadmin uses to clear the production site's database.